# Неправильная работа mysqli_multi_query

Tags: mysqli, php

Доброго времени суток!
Может ли мне кто-нибудь объяснить, почему функция mysqli_multi_query работает не корректно?
Пример:

```
$query = "TRUNCATE table;";
$query .= "INSERT INTO table(text, text2) VALUES('1', '2');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO table(text, text2) VALUES('3', '4');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO table(text, text2) VALUES('5', '6');";
$db -> multi_query($query);
```

В результате в базу записывается только первый и третий INSERT. Это происходит при любом количестве запросов (тоесть при любом кол-ве запросов всегда пропадает второй инсерт).
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: не помню точно, но если колонка называется **text**, при обработке необходимо писать:

    `table_name`.`text`

-----

А вы пробовали тоже самое выполнить в phpMyAdmin (или в любом другом месте)?

Comment: Колонка text может и не так страшно, а вот имя таблицы table -- эт' серьёзней. Странно, что первый и третий insert отрабатывают...

Comment: При выполнении в phpMyAdmin все проходит как надо. Имя таблиц и баз значения не имеют (пробовал на разных). Названия колонок просто как пример, в проекте, естественно, используются корректные названия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответа не найдено, multi_query пришлось заменить несколькими запросами.

Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: если еще с таким столкнетесь - можно включить бинарный лог для сервака и посмотреть, какие запросы на самом деле туда падают.